# Swift Playgrounds working very slow

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit, swift-playground

I am using a few different SCNActions in my Swift playground and the animations run very slowly. 
Here is an example of one of my actions

```
node.runAction(SCNAction.repeatForever(SCNAction.rotateBy(x: 0, y: 0, z:  2 * .pi, duration: 2)))
```

Also, my code for an action is in a separate class like I read online, so what could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I noticed on SSD machine it comparitevly faster.

Answer (score 2):

Are you currently using Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.3? I updated yesterday and after the update playgrounds have been running really slow. Sorry this doesn't answer your code directly but my roommates playground is really slow after the update too.

Comment: Have you try to remove the `DerivedData`  folder ?  Since swift version updated, so some cache need to clean and rebuild.